# Does SQLite's last_insert_rowid() still work with persistent database connections?

Tags: database, sqlite

It is my understanding that modern web frameworks use a **persistent database connection**. I am wondering what impact this has on SQLite's **last_insert_rowid()**.

I use **last_insert_rowid()** to get the unique ID for a previous insertion. Suppose I have a Users table currently with 22 records.  I then do:

```
insert into Users (UserName,RealName) values ('jdoe','John Doe')
select last_insert_rowid()
```

The **last_insert_rowid()** in this case returns 23. I can use this ID value to explicitly access this newly inserted record.

Now, according to the SQLite documentation, **last_insert_rowid()** only applies to the **current** connection.  So if other users are accessing the database with other connections, all is well.  But for shared / persistent database connections, is there a problem?

Imagine this scenario:

(1) User A does:

```
insert into Users (UserName,RealName) values ('jdoe','John Doe')
```

(2) User B does:

```
insert into Tools (ToolName) values ('Widget')
```

(3) User A does:

```
last_insert_rowid()
```

In this case, two users are both doing insert operations.  Although User A's steps 1 and 3 are *supposed* to be sequential, they are not.  User B's insert actually weasels its way in between.  So, in this scenario, does User A's step 3 **last_insert_rowid()** return the last row insert ID from step **1** or step **2**?  And if 2, how do you avoid this problem?

Comment: What particular web framework gives the same connection to two users at the same time?

Comment: I am using Perl Mojolicious, but mine is a general question.  It applies to all web frameworks, FastCGI, mod_perl, multi-threaded applications, etc. I'm just a little fuzzy on on how a persistent process / persistent database connection in this environment works.  Looking for a little guidance.